# Windows 10: Two user accouts with the same profile folder

Tags: windows, user-management, windows-10, user-accounts

I would like to know if its possible to have two Windows 10 user accounts share the same profile folder?
My workstation has currently only one user account (Admin) and i would like to create another user account just for RDC. I would like the latter to have access to the same settings, applications and folders as my main account. The first idea that came up was the possibility to use the same account folder for both accounts.

Is this possible? If so, how can i accomplish it? If not, other suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: No, It’s not possible.  Windows excepts specific permissions on a users profile directory.  Determine if after the initial duplication additional synchronization will be required and update your question

Comment: I think your requirements are inconsistent. If the new account is identical to the old one in all but name, what do you hope to gain by having a different log-on? If the second account is for RDC use only, why would you need the settings, etc, to be identical? What you can do is create a new account and, by renaming and replacing with directory links, direct the standard standard subdirectories (Documents, Downloads, etc) to the corresponding directories in the existing account. You _could_ do the same with `AppData`, but I would not wish to answer for the consequences.

Comment: @AFH my workstation has multiple apps opened in multiple virtual desktops, and after every RDC i have to resize and rearrange my application windows. Since my workstation has a 4K resolution and my laptop a HD one, this make me crazy every time a need to go back to my workstation. That's why i asked my question. Also, i changed the new account folder to my main profile one, but then i try to login, windows doesn't allow me to. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ricky - He did provide a suggestion.  You would have to use directory links.  You changing the profile directory to a directory owned by another user is of course going to prevent you from logging in as that profile (hence the reason I indicated what you wanted isn't possible).  I however, am not prepared to write an answer that says that, simply because I don't believe answers which are limited to "it's not possible" are not helpful (although a comment cutting to that point might be).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you mean _incoming_ RDC: I now see your problem. But your desktop layout is in your settings, and if both accounts share _all_ settings then you still have the problem. My best suggestion is to create a new account, map the main subfolders as I suggested, then **copy** `AppData`: this should give the same initial settings on both accounts, but it will not keep up with future settings changes on the main account. Where did you change the account folder? As with `AppData`, not something I'd recommend. Change it back, or delete account and profile folder, and start again.

Comment: @AFH thanks for the feedback. Honestly i'm starting to think that this is just not worth the trouble :-/ i'm going to leave things as they are for now. Once again thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each user has to have its own folder.  A viable alternative might be:

1. set up an account the way you like it.
2. have the data folders you want to be consistent across users point to a location outside the user directory (so documents points to, say, C:\Docs instead of C:\Users\username\documents)
3. create a new user account.  then, while logged in to a third administrator account, copy your old account's files over to the new account.  This ought to create a perfect clone of the old account.
4. You may need to set user permissions as appropriate for both accounts so they both know they are allowed to use the shared data folders.

I would recommend a folder synching app rather than just copying in the finder.  That way you can see that everything has copied properly and is identical between the old and new user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. First, create user account as usual, using Control Panel or **lusrmgr.msc**.

1. Reboot PC and login into your newly created account. Your new account will be assigned profile folder, located at **C:\Users\xxx** (let's assume "xxx" is the name of new account).
2. Now open regedit.exe and navigate to path "**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList**". You'll see the list of all users on a PC.
3. Alternately click on profiles, whose name starts with S-1-5-21 until you find profile with "**ProfileImagePath**" equal to C:\Users\xxx.
4. In this profile change value of "ProfileImagePath" from "C:\Users\xxx" to the path of your old profile, for example to "C:\Users\Administrator".
5. Reboot PC and you'll discover that user xxx has new profile folder. To confirm it, open CMD and enter %USERPROFILE%. The output would be: `'C:\Users\Administrator' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Personally, I have two user accounts, which share same profile folder. One account is Administrator, another one is SYSTEM (S-1-5-18).